# SDL_KEYDOWN Not Recognizing Some Keystrokes (A-Z, 0-9 & Space)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sdl-2

I'm rewriting some SDL things for practice from my Linux/Codeblocks setup to my Win7/VisStudio setup and I've hit an odd road block. SDL recognizes some keystrokes but not others. It reads the arrow keys, shift, alt, ctrl and a handful of others but it doesn't recognize a majority of keys, a-z 0-9, Space among others.

Neither:

`SDL_GetScancodeName(event->key.keysym.scancode)`
nor
`SDL_GetKeyName(event->key.keysym.sym)`
print any response from the problematic keys with a `printf` but responds fine for the working keys.

I double checked that my keyboard was set to English and I also tried a USB keyboard as opposed to my usual PS2 board just in case for some reason those were interfering but no result.

I've tried to find similar questions but I can't seem to find any that have specific keystroke problems like this.

Visual Studio 2017. SDL2, using libsdl.org's Dev libs. x86 if it matters.

**EDIT:**
I treated the symptoms but not the fever. If anyone could help I would like to have a better understanding for what went wrong and some better solutions.

I was trying to detect when no keys were being pressed, my original code was to follow:

`if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)`

with an:

`else`

for when no keys were pressed. This worked fine except for the problem keys.

I'm curious as to why this only affected some keys and possibly an alternative to detecting when no keys are pressed.

Here's an excerpt of the code I was using:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
{       
    if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_UP:
                keyPressed = "Up";
                printf("Keypress test: Up\n");
                break;
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                keyPressed = "Space";
                printf("Keypress test: Space\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }           
        }
    else
    {
        keyPressed = "None";
    }
}
```

With the `else` I can correctly return the string `keyPressed` for `SDLK_UP` but not `SDLK_SPACE`. In this case both `printf` in the switch occur so I definitely step into it but the `else` seems to overwrite the string. Removing the `else` makes both work perfectly but then I can't detect when no keys are pressed.

I assume there is just something about `SDLK_SPACE` A-Z and 0-9 that I don't understand that causes the program to step into the `else`.

I quickly made a git to post the code:
https://github.com/TorsvikVonClemson/AloeFoil00

It should display 5 shapes and a test rectangle. One for no key presses, on for each arrow key and the rect while pressing space.

Apologies if its sloppy, I haven't quite figured how to post straight from VS17.

Comment: [mcve]?  Visual Studio version?  SDL2 version?  Self-built SDL2 or off-the-shelf binaries from libsdl.org?

Comment: Can you also add the code you use to check whether a key works or not?

Comment: I can't reproduce (though I'm using MinGW-w64). Can you provide a complete example, something that we can compile ourselves?

Comment: Say keypress event fires (which is confirmed by printf), but then some other event comes - e.g. mouse move, window focus, ...... - and your marker string resets before you can use it. It is as it should be. Or even multiple keypresses happens within single iteration - how are you going to handle that?

Comment: I had figured something like that but what I don't understand is why the arrow and some mod keys work but others don't. Is there a fundamental difference between these keys that I don't understand?

Comment: @TorsvikVonClemson most likely just a coincidence. At any rate, you can't rely on that order of things - even if it is 100% reproducible for you, there is no reason to expect it to behave the same way for others. There is [SDL_GetKeyboardState](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) which probably does what you need, and without atrocious strings, but you still need to process event queue, even if you'll discard all events.

Comment: @keltar I see what you're saying. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll get working on it when I get the chance. I guess that mostly closes my question.

Comment: As to why letters and space are affected, that could be because they also generate text input events.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a question from four years ago, I still want to provide my answer to help others in need.

```
// In your main loop
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
      {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
          case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            std::cout << "I want quit game\n"; // Working
            break;
          case SDLK_p:
            std::cout << "I want pause game\n"; // Not working
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
      std::cout << event.text.text;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

If you check event type SDL_TEXTINPUT, you will find 0-9, a-z, etc. just go into `case SDL_TEXTINPUT`.

The soluction is [SDL_StopTextInput](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_StopTextInput), It's obvious:

```
// In your main loop
SDL_StopTextInput(); // Stop text input first.

SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
      {
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
          case SDLK_ESCAPE:
            std::cout << "I want quit game\n"; // Working
            break;
          case SDLK_p:
            std::cout << "I want pause game\n"; // Working now
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
      std::cout << event.text.text; // bye bye text input event 
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

If you want to reopen text input, just use [SDL_StartTextInput](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_StartTextInput).

Thanks @HolyBlackCat comment :)